# Что лучше использовать для обнаружение цвета на экране?

Tags: компьютерное-зрение

Что можно использовать для того что бы в центре экрана обнаружить заданный цвет и при его обнаружение нажимается ЛКМ?? Нужна скорость обнаружение цвета и нажатие на ЛКМ.

ЛКМ - лева кнопка мыши

Comment: Вы говорите о компьютере, имеющем программный доступ к экрану или о взгляде со стороны, через подключенную к компьютеру (или смартфону) камеру? (и поясните, что такое ЛКМ?)

Comment: @avp, ЛКМ - левая кнопка мыши